# my grid isn't working and i can't seem to find out why?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i have been trying to fix this code for school.
i've tried to tweak many things here and there but still haven't been able to figure out why my images stay to the left of the screen instead of actually making a grid, since i have used auto-fit.
i have left in some css stuff from my other html pages, but the problem could be that they're interacting with eachother so i left them in there.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


/* layout container */

.containerIndex {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.25fr 1.5fr 1.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav nav nav"
    "sidebar movies movies movies"
    "sidebar movies movies movies"
    "sidebar movies movies movies"
    "sidebar footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.containerMain {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.25fr 1.5fr 1.5fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav nav nav"
    "main main main main" 
    "main  main main main"
    "main main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer";
  grid-gap: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

<strike>Markdown this is the movie grid.</strike>
/* film overzicht images */

.movies {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

article {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
}

article img {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.overlay-text {
  align-self: end;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.overlay-text p {
  margin: 0;
}

article img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.overlay-text {
  align-self: end;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.overlay-text p {
  margin: 0;
}

.airwolf_afbeelding {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.airwolf_video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 200px;
}


/* netflix naam en logo */

.logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -24px;
  width: 88px;
}

nav {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: large;
  background: #8a0c03;
  grid-area: nav;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


/* Menu */

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1400px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #8a0c03;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8a0c03;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -57px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #8a0c03;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #8a0c03;
}


/* tabel */

table,
th,
td {
  BORDER: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  background-color: #8a0c03;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}


/* algemene opmaak */

main {
  background: #000000;
  color: #8a0c03;
  grid-area: main;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.movies {
  background: #000000;
  color: #8a0c03;
  grid-area: movies;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
  background: #8a0c03;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

footer {
  background: #8a0c03;
  grid-area: footer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1rem;
}


/* resize voor kleinere devices */

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .containerIndex {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.25fr 0.4fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "nav"
      "sidebar"
      "dropdown"
      "main"
      "footer";
  }
  .containerMain {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.25fr 0.4fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "nav"
      "dropdown"
      "main"
      "footer";
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 366.5px;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerIndex">

  <nav>
    <a class="button" href="Index.html"><img src="/images/LogoF.jpg" class="logo" alt="LogoF">
    </a>
    <h1>F l e t n i x</h1>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="inloggen.html">Inloggen</a>
        <a href="registeren.html">Registreren</a>
        <a href="over_ons.html">Over ons</a>
        <a href="privacy_verklaring.html">Privacy verklaring</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <movies>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Airwolf.jpg" alt="Airwolf">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Airwolf</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Annie.jpg" alt="Annie">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Annie</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Baywatch.jpg" alt="Baywatch">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Baywatch</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Clueless.jpg" alt="Clueless">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Clueless</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Deadpool.jpg" alt="Deadpool">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Deadpool</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Election.jpg" alt="Election">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Election</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Fences.jpg" alt="Fences">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Fences</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Friends.jpg" alt="Friends">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Friends</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Fringe.jpg" alt="Fringe">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Fringe</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Frozen.jpg" alt="Frozen">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Frozen</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Gravity.jpg" alt="Gravity">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Gravity</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Her.jpg" alt="Her">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Her</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Madagascar.jpg" alt="Madagascar">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Madagascar</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Maleficent.jpg" alt="Maleficent">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Maleficent</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Moneyball.jpg" alt="Moneyball">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Moneyball</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Ratatouille.jpg" alt="Ratatouille">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Ratatouille</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Rio.jpg" alt="Rio">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Rio</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Roseanne.jpg" alt="Roseanne">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Roseanne</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Salt.jpg" alt="Salt">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Salt</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Serpico.jpg" alt="Serpico">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Serpico</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Shrek.jpg" alt="Shrek">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Shrek</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Titanic.jpg" alt="Titanic">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Titanic</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Twilight.jpg" alt="Twilight">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Twilight</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Vaiana.jpg" alt="Vaiana">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Vaiana</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Wanted.jpg" alt="Wanted">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Wanted</p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <img src="/movies/Wild.jpg" alt="Wild">
      <div class="overlay-text">
        <p>Wild</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </movies>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <label for="zoeken">zoeken:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="zoeken" name="zoeken" ><br>
  </label>
    <br>
    <br> Genre's:
    <br>
    <br> Actie
    <br>
    <br> Comedy
    <br>
    <br> Animatie
    <br>
    <br> drama
    <br>
    <br> avontuur
    <br>
    <br> romantisch
    <br>
    <br> thriller



  </div>
  <footer>
    © FletNix - 2021

  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `<movies>` is not an HTML element, thus rendering your HTML **invalid**. You cannot just come up with your own tag names; if you need that, make sure to follow the rules for valid custom element names. That being said, any `grid` you define on any element can only affect its **direct child elements**. Your `body` only has **one such**: `<div class="containerIndex">`

Answer (score 0):

You have `display:grid` on your articles

Put `display:grid` on movies also make sure to change `<movies>` to `<div class="movies">` for your css in .movies to actually work

You also need to state how many columns you want on a row by doing `grid-template-columns` in your .movies css file. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

For example `grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr` will get you 3 columns